# Parse-Server Rest API HTTP Authentication

Tags: rest, ssl, https, npm, parse-server

I can not get the Rest API to work with Basic Authentication like in the guide i.e. https://myAppID:javascript-key=myJavaScriptKey@api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm.

I can make it work if I use curl and pass the keys via HTTP Headers, however I'm trying to use a WebHook from another service and I don't have the ability to send HTTP headers.

2 issues when trying locally:

http(s) does not work even locally.
http gives me error:unauthorized.

I'm using parse-server installed via npm globally but don't see a place to add cert.

Please help!

Comment: without access to http headers it will not work.. re testing on localhost. IMO i t may be easier to run the server as http only and , for your testing to front it with a simple proxy to downgrade https--> http. that approach can be easier than drilling all the cert stuff for end to end https.

Comment: Thanks Robert,  I'm fine with using http only for now, however I can't get http to work locally without the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use http local and remote using the format http://myAppId:myMasterKey@mydomain.com:1337/parse/classes/myClass and it worked fine.  If you use Postman you have to turn on Basic Auth in the header section.

Comment: Any configuration you had to make on the server? I can make the request from Postman successfully but not from HTTP